# Coding Chatroom in C. Getting repeated messages

Tags: c

For some reason when I type a long message followed by a shorter message in my chatroom. I end up getting back the shorter message, followed by the remaining character in the previous message on the next line. In the server window it states it is receiving the messed up message so I assume the problem is in my client code, probably in my writing_messages thread. What is the issue?

```
//CLIENT CODE for writing and reading messages:

void* writing_messages(void* arg) 
{
    char    unfinished_message[2028];
    char    new_msg[2048];
    while(fgets(unfinished_message, sizeof(unfinished_message), stdin))
    {
        strcat(new_msg, arg);    //My arg is a user_name I enter in the cmdline
        strcat(new_msg,": ");
        strcat(new_msg, unfinished_message);
        write(SD, new_msg, strlen(new_msg));
        strcpy(new_msg, "");
        strcpy(unfinished_message, "");
    }
}
void* reading_messages(void* arg) 
{
    char    got_message[2048];
    while(1)
    {
        read(SD, got_message, sizeof(got_message));
        printf("%s\n", got_message);
    }
}
//SERVER CODE for receiving messages

void *
client_session_thread(void * arg)
{
    int     SD;
    char    request[2048];
    char    message[2048] = "server receives input: ";

    SD = *(int *)arg;
    free (arg);
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    while (read(SD, request, sizeof(request)))
    {
        strcat(message, request);
        strcat(message,"\n");
        fprintf(stdout, message);
        write(SD,request,strlen(request));
        strcpy(request,"");
        strcpy(message, "server receives input: ");
    }
    close(SD);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `write(SD, new_msg, strlen(new_msg))`. This writes the message without the terminating `'\0'`. Because of this (among other problems),  there's no reason, `got_message` should have a string terminator at all (hello, buffer overrun) client side. Side note: `read()` is quite likely to return short without a complete message.

Comment: Okay so where would I have to plugin the "/0" to terminate the message so ever written message contains no previous message fragments? @dhke

Comment: You are using C-style strings, the `'\0'` is already there (put there by `fgets()`) at the end of the source string. It's *not* included in `strlen()` though. You actually need to write `strlen() + 1` bytes.

Comment: `/*int x = */read(SD, got_message, sizeof(got_message));` ... What do you think `x` might be?